# Show pic cover pdf in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have pdf reader with listview with icon pdf
and how to make cover pdf show in listview like this?

[image: Example 1]

or

[image: Example 2]

source code: https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/24/open-pdf-file-from-sdcard-in-android-programmatically/

How to change pdf icon to cover pdf in listview?

thanks

Main Activity.java

```
ListView lv_pdf;
public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
PDFAdapter obj_adapter;
public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
boolean boolean_permission;
File dir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();


}

private void init() {
    lv_pdf = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pdf);
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"Pdf");
    fn_permission();
    lv_pdf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", i);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("Position", i + "Pdf");
        }
    });
}

public static ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                getfile(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                boolean booleanpdf = false;
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                        if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                            booleanpdf = true;
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                    if (booleanpdf) {
                        booleanpdf = false;
                    } else {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return fileList;
}

private void fn_permission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {


        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

        }
    } else {
        boolean_permission = true;

        getfile(dir);

        obj_adapter = new PDFAdapter(getApplicationContext(), fileList);
        lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            boolean_permission = true;
            getfile(dir);

            obj_adapter = new PDFAdapter(getApplicationContext(), fileList);
            lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

PdfActivity

```
 public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
PDFView pdfView;
Integer pageNumber = 0;
String pdfFileName;
String TAG = "PdfActivity";
int position = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    //position = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sdcard/Pdf"
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
    displayFromSdcard();
    //String position = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/Pdf/";
}

private void displayFromSdcard() {
    pdfFileName = MainActivity.fileList.get(position).getName();

    pdfView.fromFile(MainActivity.fileList.get(position))
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .password("123456")
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .load();
}


@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
    pageNumber = page;
    setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
}


@Override
public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
    PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
    printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

}

public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
    for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

        Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

        if (b.hasChildren()) {
            printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
        }
    }
}
```

PdfAdapter

```
 Context context;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
ArrayList<File> al_pdf;

public PDFAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> al_pdf) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_pdf, al_pdf);
    this.context = context;
    this.al_pdf = al_pdf;

}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    if (al_pdf.size() > 0) {
        return al_pdf.size();
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_pdf, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv_filename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    viewHolder.tv_filename.setText(al_pdf.get(position).getName());
    return view;

}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_filename;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the image by creating the bitmap of pdf first page. Then save the image to your app directory to be used later. You can use PdfiumCore (which is dependency of barteks PdfView) to generate the image.

You can use the following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class PDFUtils {

  static String generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(Context context, Uri uri, long bookId) {
    try {
      ParcelFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
      int pageNum = 0;
      PdfiumCore pdfiumCore = new PdfiumCore(context);
      try {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
        pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, 0); // open first page for cover.

        int width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum);
        int height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum);

        // do a fit center to 1920x1080
        //double scaleBy = Math.min(1080 / (double) width, //
        //    1920 / (double) height);
        //width = (int) (width * scaleBy);
        //height = (int) (height * scaleBy);

        // ARGB_8888 - best quality, high memory usage, higher possibility of OutOfMemoryError
        // RGB_565 - little worse quality, twice less memory usage
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bitmap, pageNum, 0, 0, width, height);
        //if you need to render annotations and form fields, you can use
        //the same method above adding 'true' as last param

        String fileName = bookId + ".jpg";
        // save the file
        File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        // a bit long running
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
        fd.close();
        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument); // important!

        return fileName;
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Then, you need to use the class by using the following:

```
long bookId = 2345; // your book identifier
Url yourPdfUrl; // url of pdf in your device
PdfUtils.generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(context, yourPdfUrl, bookId);
```

After you have saved the image, you can use the image again with something like this:

```
String imagePath = getFilesDir() + "/" + yourBookId + ".jpg";
```

Comment: im new in android
how to get book id?
because my pdf programmatically

Comment: You need to create the bookId manually. Usually you're creating an id using the unique identifier like isbn or the book name.

Comment: are you from indo?
can you teach me and i do not understand what you mean?
and how to show pic pdf because my pdf random from sdcard

Comment: i mean like foxit PDF in android

Comment: Yes, I'm from Indonesia. You can use the class in my answer. For the `bookId`, it is  the id used to save your image in the internal storage. So, whenever you want to show the image, you can get it by the id.

Comment: bahasa indo aja boleh kali ya hehe

Comment: long bookId = 2345; // your book identifier
Url yourPdfUrl; // url of pdf in your device
PdfUtils.generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(context, yourPdfUrl, bookId);

yg ini taro dimana?
saya taro di on create error gk mau jalan

Comment: at com.pdffilefromsdcard.PdfUtils.generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(PdfUtils.java:19)
        at com.pdffilefromsdcard.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:57)
        at com.pdffilefromsdcard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7046)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)

Comment: We can't use bahasa Indonesia sir. You need to add the line after you opening the file. It's used to generate your pdf image. After it's generated, you can access it with `String fileName = bookId + ".jpg";
        File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);`

Comment: at com.example.asus.testpdfutils.PDFUtils.generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(PDFUtils.java:20)
        at com.example.asus.testpdfutils.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7046)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2930) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)

Comment: my code:
long bookId = 1; 
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://androhub.com/demo/demo.pdf");
 PDFUtils.generateAndSaveFirstPageImage(context, uri, bookId);